# Как ограничить по времени, доступ по пин-коду?

Tags: php

Создал простенькую проверку пин-кода пришедшего в post запросе

```
<?php
$pinlist = array_filter(array_map('intval', file(__DIR__ . '/pinlist.txt')));

###
#... еще код ...
###

$pin_code = $_POST["pin_code"];

if (!in_array($pin_code, $pinlist)) {
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo 'Пин-код недействителен или просрочен';
exit;   
}

###
#... Если пин-код есть в файле pinlist.txt выполняю остальной код ниже к которому и закрыт доступ по пин-коду ...
###
```

**Как ограничить по времени, доступ по такому пин-коду?**

Может быть можно как-то в момент первой проверки пин-кода, во время первого post запроса, пришедшему пин-коду назначить временную метку прямо в файле pinlist.txt? Что будет после **второго post с данным пин-кодом**, т.е. как дать скрипту понять, что для  данного кода уже есть временная метка.

К примеру, хочу чтобы пин-код работал ровно 3 месяца.

Файл pinlist.txt содержит строки с дефолтными пин-кодами:

```
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
и т.д.
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при первой проверке пин-кода 2222222222, ему **было установлено временное ограничение на 3 месяца** и через 3 месяца, данный пин-код (строка) **самоудалился из файла pinlist.txt**?

Чтобы при следующей проверке, пин-код отсутствовал в файле и закрытый скрипт не выполнился.

p.s. pinlist.txt можно сделать php файлом, буду рад вашим рекомендациям, советам. Возможно как-то проще все можно реализовать, помогите, пожалуйста.

Спасибо!

Comment: Почему решили хранить данные в .txt файле? Почему не база данных?

Comment: С базой слишком сложно, post запросы должны приходить очень часто, решил, что проще делать проверку по файлу. В общем это максимум который я смог сделать.

Comment: Если запросы будут приходить слишком часто, то Вы уверены, что юзер www-data не попытается открыть файл, когда он уже был открыт? Не произойдет ли блокировки файла?

Comment: Тестировал довольно долго, блокировок нет.

Comment: @MicroRu вы хотите реализовать это только для одного пользователя? Если да, то можно записывать время считывания пинкода рядом с пинкодом _(или в отдельном файле)_, и проверять при последующих запросах к этому пинкоду, не истекло ли время. Но вот если для многих юзеров _(что вполне логично)_, то ещё понадобится какая-то авторизация, и в таком случае наверное будет лучше использовать БД вместо текст.файла.

Answer (score 1):

Можно при помощи time() устанавливать текущее время, ну а после сравнивать. Но как минимум хранить все в файле неправильно.